# Pass JQuery variables to php

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want to pass jQuery variable to php file ,
this is my_js.js file

```
  function updates() {
         $.getJSON("php/fetch.php", function(data) {
           $.each(data.result, function(){

            var s_id = this['sender_id'];        
           });
     });
    }
```

and i want to display it here in php file,

```
<html>
<head><title>Pass jquery var to php file</title>
</head>
<body>

<div> <?php echo $s_id ; ?> </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="my_js.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't do it like that. `$s_id` is not defined. The information you want to display is not yet on the page?

Comment: think of it this way, the php code will be run before the javascript code is run. simply because , the php code runs on the server and the javascript code is run on the client ( browser )

Comment: @putvande i know , that '$s_id' is not defined , that why i post this question here , to know how to pass that variable from 'my_js.js' file to 'indexd.php' so i can display it . if you know how please show me.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using jQuery to set the s_id value in the page.

You can modify your HTML as follows (the important part being the added `span` element):

```
<html>
    <head><title>Pass jquery var to php file</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div><span id="s_id"></span></div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="my_js.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And you can use jQuery in your getJSON callback to set the value as follows to find your added `span` element and modify its text:

```
function updates() {
     $.getJSON("php/fetch.php", function(data) {
       $.each(data.result, function(){

        $("#s_id").text(this['sender_id']);        
       });
 });
}
```

Comment: thanks but i want that variable to use it in function call something like '<button onclick="to('a','that variable here')">send</button>' my idea is '<button onclick="to('a','<?php echo $s_id?>')">send</button>' but i can't pass it , please if you have any idea.

Comment: You might reconsider your approach for that. You could put the value of that variable as an attribute on your button and then grab that value in your onclick function using jQuery

Comment: how can i do that please.

Comment: Check out the attr() documentation on the jQuery site: https://api.jquery.com/attr/ and give it a shot yourself

Comment: i try with it a lot but i didn't succeed . thanks anyway for your help.

Comment: You can update your question with what you've tried if you still need help